# How to delete audioClip from Sonos

Tags: sonos

I'm trying to play an audioClip on my Sonos player and cancel it after a few seconds (just playing around at this point). According to [Sonos documentation](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/audioclip/cancelaudioclip/), I should make a DELETE call to `/players/{playerId}/audioClip/{id}`. There's already some confusion here because below, in their example, they show `DELETE https://api.ws.sonos.com/control/api/v1/households/{{householdId}}/players/{{playerId}}/audioClip/{id}`.

So here's what I do:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer myToken" "https://api.ws.sonos.com/control/api/v1/players/RINCON_XXXXX/audioClip" -d '{"appId":"myAppId", "name":"song", "streamUrl":"https://whatever.com/song.mp3", "priority":"HIGH"}'
{"id":"8","name":"song","appId":"myAppId","priority":"HIGH","clipType":"CUSTOM"}
```

This works properly and the audioClip starts playing on my Sonos.

Here's where it goes wrong:

```
curl -X DELETE -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer myToken" "https://api.ws.sonos.com/control/api/v1/players/RINCON_XXXXX/audioClip/8"
{"errorCode":"ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_COMMAND","reason":"Command not found"}
```

I tried to follow the other structure (including the households in the URI) but that didn't help.

It's running the softwareVersion 57.4-83220 and apiVersion 1.18.9.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say the `id` is:

> The identifier of the audio clip from the playAudioClip response.

So maybe it's returning another ID, different to the ID you used to to identify the clip.

Comment: Well, their response to my POST request is
`{"id":"8","name":"song","appId":"myAppId","priority":"HIGH","clipType":"CUSTOM"}`
So that's the id I use (8)

Comment: Fair enough - I note it says here https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/audioclip/ "Note: This namespace is experimental. Some of the functionality may not yet work as documented."